# Meter Redis Scaling update `could not find the collection`

Tags: mongodb, meteor, redis, mongodb-oplog

I added Meteor redis oplog scaling these days but it keeps showing below errors.

```
meteor add cultofcoders:redis-oplog
meteor add disable-oplog


W20200206-03:35:20.827(0)? (STDERR) error caught on publication:  undefined :  [We could not find the collection instance by name: "users", the cursor description was: {"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"z45bpfpdMX4vPSteS"},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"profile":1,"username":1,"emails":1}}}]
I20200206-03:35:24.615(0)? Exception in defer callback: { Error: [We could not find the collection instance by name: "users", the cursor description was: {"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"z45bpfpdMX4vPSteS","services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken":"6YlvkDBQYEgZRjUEzNkKiy/uVKLshey1KuJe1kPVGes="},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"_id":1}}}]
I20200206-03:35:24.616(0)?     at new ObservableCollection (packages/cultofcoders:redis-oplog/lib/cache/ObservableCollection.js:41:19)
I20200206-03:35:24.616(0)?     at new RedisOplogObserveDriver (packages/cultofcoders:redis-oplog/lib/mongo/RedisOplogObserveDriver.js:37:37)
I20200206-03:35:24.617(0)?     at MongoConnection.<anonymous> (packages/cultofcoders:redis-oplog/lib/mongo/observeChanges.js:123:25)
I20200206-03:35:24.617(0)?     at MongoConnection.mongoConnectionProto._observeChanges (packages/mdg:meteor-apm-agent/lib/hijack/wrap_observers.js:164:38)
I20200206-03:35:24.617(0)?     at Cursor.observeChanges (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:947:22)
I20200206-03:35:24.618(0)?     at Cursor.cursorProto.(anonymous function) (packages/mdg:meteor-apm-agent/lib/hijack/db.js:131:32)
I20200206-03:35:24.618(0)?     at Cursor.kadira_Cursor_observeChanges [as observeChanges] (packages/mdg:meteor-apm-agent/lib/hijack/set_labels.js:84:41)
I20200206-03:35:24.618(0)?     at Meteor.defer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:895:36)
I20200206-03:35:24.619(0)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1234:12)
I20200206-03:35:24.619(0)?     at packages/meteor.js:550:25
I20200206-03:35:24.619(0)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1286:24)
I20200206-03:35:24.620(0)?   isClientSafe: true,
I20200206-03:35:24.620(0)?   error: 'We could not find the collection instance by name: "users", the cursor description was: {"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"z45bpfpdMX4vPSteS","services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken":"6YlvkDBQYEgZRjUEzNkKiy/uVKLshey1KuJe1kPVGes="},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"_id":1}}}',
```

anyone who can help in this position?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't really provided enough information for anyone to help you. Are these client side errors or server side errors? Is it trying to find a `users` collection in redis?

Answer (score 1):

I found something useful here: https://github.com/cult-of-coders/redis-oplog/issues/317
In order to make it works, you must change the orders of packages. It's very tricky.